# Look up walking time (calculated by Google maps) between two addresses (in a Google spreadsheet)

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with one column of physical addresses, and I want to have a second column be the time in minutes to walk between the address in column 1 and a second address (as determined by Google Maps). Any recommendations on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the Google Maps terms of service, they:

- don't like people using their service as a "batch geocoder". This means that

  - you will need to throttle your requests (place delays between each successive request, to avoid the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error)
  - it is against the terms of service to use the geocoder (and maybe the distance service) without displaying a map graphic

If you still want to proceed,

- you need some way of extracting the address from your spreadsheet. I think there's a Google docs API that will help you do that. I also found some custom Javascript code that does that for you easily. I don't have a link anymore :(
- once you have the addresses readable from the Google Maps Javascript API, you can call the distance or directions API to get the walking distance
- then you need to save that back to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a possible application for the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/).

But you can only [use it if you will be displaying a map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits)

> Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of
>   information on a Google Map; for example, to determine
>   origin-destination pairs that fall within a specific driving time from
>   one another, before requesting and displaying those destinations on a
>   map. Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a
>   Google map is prohibited.

Comment: I'm just compiling a google spreadsheet for myself as I'm looking at potential apartments to rent -- and I want to know how long the walk from each potential apartment to my work is going to be.